# Access Google Apps Global Address List from Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, google-workspace

We're considering using `Google Apps` as groupware, with our Mac and Linux users (and likely a few of the Windows users as well) accessing mail and calendar using `Thunderbird with Lightning`. We seem to have worked out most features, but have not found a way to access `Global Address List`.

Is there a way to sync the Global Address List to Thunderbird?

Update: The Zindus addon as suggested by @superuser, does not have support for Global Address List from Google Apps (it does however support GAL from a Zimbra server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an addon called Zindus. It should be able to sync your Global Address List as well as your personal address book.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/zindus/

Comment: Unfortunately Zindus only support GAL from Zimbra, not from Google :(

Comment: Maybe try https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/ I personally have not used this, and the project doesn't look very active, and there seems to be a few bugs they have to work out. So, proceed with CAUTION.

Comment: No Global Address List in that one either. Thanks anyway :)